# slow update of large JSON File

Tags: python, json

I have a large JSON file that contains serialized json dicts. I am trying to iterate this file and update based on the contents of another dict. The JSON file looks similar to:

```
 sample_json = {
  "targets": [
    {
      "start": 40,
      "end": 73,
      "item": "trust:team_member",
      "lookup": "the cathedral"
    },
    {
      "start": 40,
      "end": 74,
      "item": "contact",
      "lookup": "some text"
    }
  ]},{
    "targets": [
    {
      "start": 40,
      "end": 73,
      "item": "trust:team_member",
      "lookup": "the cats"
    },
    {
      "start": 40,
      "end": 74,
      "item": "music",
      "lookup": "some other music note"
    }
  ]
}
```

The function below, iterates each line of the JSON file and creates a "key_value" that's a concatenation of item and lookup key value pairs.

```
def new_json(qle_folder, param_values):
    new_json = []
    files = [os.path.join(qle_folder, f) for f in os.listdir(qle_folder) if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(qle_folder, f))]

    for filename in files:
        with open(filename) as f:
            lines = f.readlines()
            total = len(lines)
            desc = filename
            for l in tqdm(lines, total=total, desc=desc):
                doc = json.loads(l)
                targets = len(doc['targets'])
                if targets_length == 0:
                    continue               
                item_dict = defaultdict(list)


                for i in range(target_entities_length):
                    item = doc['targets'][i]['item'].strip().lower()
                    lookup = doc['targets'][i]['lookup'].strip().lower()
                    d={'param_type': item, 'param_value': lookup}
                    key_value = str(d).strip().lower()
                    key_value = json.dumps(key_value)
                    try:
                        value= param_values[key_value] 
                        value= str(value).strip("[]\"'").lower()
                        item_dict[item].append(value)
                    except KeyError:
                        #print(f'key error: {key_values}')
                        continue
                  
                
                if item_dict:
                    item_dict = dict(item_dict)
                    
                    doc['items'] ={}
                    doc['items']['Tags']= item_dict
                else:
                    continue
                    
         
                doc = json.dumps(doc)
                qle_index.append(doc + '\n')
    
    return qle_index
```

The function seems to run really slow and freezes half way through.

```
param_values = {'{"param_type": "trust:team_member", "param_value": "the cathedral"}': ["['test 1', 'test 3', 'test 4']"],
 '{"param_type": "contact", "param_value": "some text"}': ["[''test 5', 'test 3', 'test 4'']"]}
```

Comment: What is `tqdm`?  Why store this result as a list of json-serialized data? What logic is `bool(dict) == True` trying to encapsulate?

Comment: What's the `if bool(dict) == True:` for? It should always be `True` unless you overwrote `dict`.

Comment: This function is almost certainly becoming slow because you are loading all of these json files into memory and then keeping them there, in the form of a array of json-formatted strings - how big are the files?  It would make much more sense to apply a read-update-write function to your files one by one

Comment: Not every row in the file will have a label_dict created. I have added this in to avoid blank dicts for label dict being added. I probably don't need it. So I can remove.

Comment: it's 7million rows with a JSON dict for each row,

Comment: That logic would be `if item_dict:`, not `if bool(dict) == True` =)

Comment: The file is not JSON then, but line-separated JSON?

Comment: Yes line-seperated JSON

Comment: Is `label` constant or a typo of something else

Comment: That’s a typo. I’ve corrected.

Comment: It needs to be said here.  JSON is NOT a substitute for a database.

Comment: At some point you should use an off-the-shelf data store or database rather than trying to roll your own; 7 million rows is almost certainly well past that point...

Comment: We plan to do that. This is to test something out as a one off task.

Comment: @sabik personal anecdote: I rolled my own database to store information about some machines when I was working IT. When we got to 200 rows, I moved to SQL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a lot of strange things in your code, I removed several of them in an attempt to give you something that isn't slow.

Start with something that separates your logic and lets you avoid storing stuff in memory.  This reads the tmp file at the end and replays it over, but you could also just do a file-level rename if you wanted (or keep the new one, etc.)

```
def update_qle(qle_path, tag_lookup):
    with tempfile.TemporaryFile() as tmp:
        with open(qle_path, "rb") as f:
            for json_line in f:
                data = json.loads(json_line)
                if successfully_modified_in_place(data, tag_lookup):
                    writeLine(tmp, data)
        tmp.seek(0)
        with open(qle_path, "wb") as f:
            f.write(tmp.read())
```

This leaves `convert` and `writeLine` to be defined.  Your original logic has strange behavior but I think it is supposed to look like this

```
def successfully_modified_in_place(data, tag_lookup):
    tags = {}
    for target in data["targets"]:
        item = target["item"].strip().lower()
        lookup = target["lookup"].strip().lower()
        tag = tag_lookup.get(item, {}).get(lookup)
        if not tag:
            continue
        tags[item] = tag
    data["items"] = {"Tags": tags}
    return bool(tags)

def writeLine(fp, data):
    fp.write((json.dumps(data) + "\n").encode())
```

A testable `main` function might look like this:

```
def main():
    data = [
        {
            "targets": [
                {"start": 40, "end": 73, "item": "trust:team_member", "lookup": "the cathedral"},
                {"start": 40, "end": 74, "item": "contact", "lookup": "some text"},
            ]
        },
        {
            "targets": [
                {"start": 40, "end": 73, "item": "trust:team_member", "lookup": "the cats"},
                {"start": 40, "end": 74, "item": "music", "lookup": "some other music note"},
            ]
        },
    ]
    path = "./data.jsonLines"
    with open(path, "wb") as f:
        for item in data:
            writeLine(f, item)
    lookup = {
        "trust:team_member": {"the cathedral": "test 1 test 3 test 4"},
        "contact": {"some text": "test 5 test 3 test 4"},
    }
    update_qle(path, lookup)
```

which we would expect to generate a file like

```
{
  "targets": [
    {
      "start": 40,
      "end": 73,
      "item": "trust:team_member",
      "lookup": "the cathedral"
    },
    {
      "start": 40,
      "end": 74,
      "item": "contact",
      "lookup": "some text"
    }
  ],
  "items": {
    "Tags": {
      "trust:team_member": "test 1 test 3 test 4",
      "contact": "test 5 test 3 test 4"
    }
  }
}
```

since the second element of data has no matching tags, so will be skipped.

Comment: i've managed to get `successfully_modified_in_place` working but I keep getting an error with `update_qle`. The error i get is `TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes`

Comment: edited to change `open(..., 'w')` to `open(..., 'wb')`, should be fine after that

Comment: It's still not working. I need to write this as json.dumps(). I've tried and can't get it to work.